# Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory

Tags: node.js, express

I have this error in my express.js project:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory
```

I would like to redirect by a route into an html page.

I create a form that send to the route **inserToDB** a name and a surname.
I would like to redirect in the **profile.ejs** page but i find always this error.

I don't understand the reason. So i'll post my code in the hope that you can help me..

**app.js**

```
var routes = require('./routes/routes');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// view engine setup
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

**route.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log("index.ejs è caricata!");
  res.render('index.ejs');
});

router.get('/profile', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Ok ci siamo: profile caricata!");
    res.render('profile.ejs');
});

router.get('/insertToDB', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query.name + req.query.surname);
    res.redirect("/profile");
});

module.exports = router;
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Ciao loschi! 
Inserisci i tuoi dati
<div>
    Nome <input type="text" name="name" id="name"></input>
    <br>
    Cognome<input type="text" name="surname" id="surname"></input>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="Invia" id="enter"></input>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/action.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**action.js**

```
$("#enter").on("click", function(){
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var surname = $("#surname").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "/insertToDB",
      data:"name=" + name +"&surname="+ surname,
      async:"true"
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have an error view in your views directory? It looks like express wants to display an error to the user but can't find the view to do so. Maybe include a file like this in your views folder, if it doesn't exist already: https://github.com/expressjs/generator/blob/master/templates/ejs/error.ejs

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your engine setup in `app.js` to:

```
// view engine setup
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

Then change your error handler in `app.js` to:

```
// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error.ejs');
});
```

And don't forget to create a `.ejs` file called `error.ejs` in the views directory. This should fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

--pls save the folders name view to views

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).